# Is there a term for an international market in which firms cannot break even without subsidisation?

Tags: international-economics, definition

There are (and have historically been) various sectors whose firms frequently receive subsidies from their home government, for instance because they are perceived as "strategic".  Is there a term to describe a global market in which subsidies are so commonplace that a firm operating at the practical limit of efficiency would not be viable without subsidisation?